Wordpress load stylesheet last at the bottom of the page below all other stylesheets
I have some spreadsheets that load at the bottom of the page for a couple of plugins (e.g. Ultimate Member and Open User Map).
I have a child theme stylesheet, but some of the styles in the plugins are already set to important, so I am trying to over-ride them but since they are marked important, my changes in my stylesheet do not work for those elements.
How can I load an additional stylesheet below them?
Thanks

You can use a higher priority like below code when you enqueue your stylesheets
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this, 'theme_styles'), 99 

Note : Use higher number in priority to load at last

I have done that in the HEAD for my main stylesheet but I want another in the WP footer., as in the bottom of the page under where the plugin has its stylesheets loaded.

You can do this in multiple ways with wp_enqueue_script:

When you enqueue your css file, set the dependency array to rely on the plugins stylesheet. Look through the plugin code and see where and how they enqueue their stylesheet, use that handle/name in your enqueue for the dependency. Keep in mind that if the dependency is not correct, or does not exist, your stylesheet will not be enqueued, WP doesn't output a warning for this.
wp_enqueue_script(
    $handle,
    $src,
    [
        'handle-of-plugin-stylesheet'
    ],
    $ver,
    $args
);


In addition, you can set the $args parameter to defer and place in footer like so:
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, [
    'strategy' => 'defer',
    'in_footer' => true,
]);


Less pretty solution; Use the wp_footer hook to insert the stylesheet there:
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_styles_footer', 99 );
function custom_styles_footer () {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/footer-styles.css" media="all" />';
}




Hope that helps.
